# How to include loading gif while file upload and insert to database is in progress

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have to load a file into a temporary location first before reading it and inserting it into a database. But how can I include a loading gif while its doing all of these, can someone please show me? -Thanks

```
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<input type="submit"  id = "upload" value="Upload">    
<div id= "loading_gif">
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#upload").click(function () {     

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: {
            file: myfile
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Data has been Uploaded: ");
          }
       });
     });
  });



<?php
$temp_location = "tmp/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{    
  if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
  {
     echo "File loading error! ";
  }
  else
  {        
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],
    $temp_location. $_FILES["myfile"]       ["name"]);

    //read myfile and insert data into database

    echo "File uploaded into database";
   } 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see your AJAX implementation

Comment: How you display a loading GIF has NOTHING to do with what is happening on the SERVER because the GIF is on the BROWSER.

Comment: @esqew I have edited it. Its now there

Comment: Standard AJAX can't upload a file anyways... this will never work as written. Plus, your server side code is a hideous security risk and you are opening your server to a COMPLETE remote compromise. Stop working on this code until you've learned how to handle uploads securely

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have an image `loading.gif`.
put it into `img` tag and set it's `id` to 'loading', and then make it invisible.

```
<img id='loading' src='loading.gif' style='visibility: hidden;'>
```

You have to create javascript functions to show and hide the loading image. Here's the script:

```
<script>
function showLoading(){
document.getElementById("loading").style = "visibility: visible";
}
function hideLoading(){
document.getElementById("loading").style = "visibility: hidden";
}
</script>
```

To show the loading image when you are uploading, call the `showLoading()` function jus before the ajax call, and then hide it when you are done uploading with `hideLoading()` function.
Here's the implementation :

```
$("#upload").click(function () {     
    //call show loading function here
    showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: {
            file: myfile
        },
        success: function () {
            //call hide function here
            hideLoading();
            alert("Data has been Uploaded: ");
        },
        error  : function (a) {//if an error occurs
            hideLoading();
            alert("An error occured while uploading data.\n error code : "+a.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

And I know you know where you have to put the jquery script inthe document. :D

Answer (score 0):

Now you should have JQUERY for that. try to put the following code in the `<head>` part of your code, this loads the jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

put the hidden gif loader somewhere u want to display

```
<img id="loading_gif" src="loading.gif" />
```

Hide it on page load: `$('#loading_gif').hide();`

now in javascript show and hide the loader

```
function submit()
{
    $('#loading_gif').show();
    // do your upload stuff
    $('#loading_gif').hide();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
.ajax_overlay {}
.ajax_loader {background: url("loading.gif") no-repeat center center transparent;width:100%;height:100%;}
</style>  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    function ajaxLoader (el, options) {
        // Becomes this.options
        var defaults = {
            bgColor         : '#fff',
            duration        : 800,
            opacity         : 0.7,
            classOveride    : false
        }
        this.options    = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
        this.container  = $(el);

    this.init = function() {
        var container = this.container;
        // Delete any other loaders
        this.remove(); 
        // Create the overlay 
        var overlay = $('<div></div>').css({
                'background-color': this.options.bgColor,
                'opacity':this.options.opacity,
                'width':container.width(),
                'height':container.height(),
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0px',
                'left':'0px',
                'z-index':99999
        }).addClass('ajax_overlay');
        // add an overiding class name to set new loader style 
        if (this.options.classOveride) {
            overlay.addClass(this.options.classOveride);
        }
        // insert overlay and loader into DOM 
        container.append(
            overlay.append(
                $('<div></div>').addClass('ajax_loader')
            ).fadeIn(this.options.duration)
        );
    };

    this.remove = function(){
        var overlay = this.container.children(".ajax_overlay");
        if (overlay.length) {
            overlay.fadeOut(this.options.classOveride, function() {
                overlay.remove();
            });
        }   
    }

    this.init();
}   
</script>

</script>
var loader;
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   
        loader = new ajaxLoader('body', options);
    });
var options = {
    bgColor         : '#fff',
    duration        : 800,
    opacity     : 0.7,
    classOveride    : false
}


$(document).ajaxcomplete(function(){    
            if (loader) loader.remove();
        });
</script>
```

for your code

```
<style>
.ajax_overlay {}
.ajax_loader {background: url("loading.gif") no-repeat center center transparent;width:100%;height:100%;}
</style>  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    function ajaxLoader (el, options) {
        // Becomes this.options
        var defaults = {
            bgColor         : '#fff',
            duration        : 800,
            opacity         : 0.7,
            classOveride    : false
        }
        this.options    = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
        this.container  = $(el);

    this.init = function() {
        var container = this.container;
        // Delete any other loaders
        this.remove(); 
        // Create the overlay 
        var overlay = $('<div></div>').css({
                'background-color': this.options.bgColor,
                'opacity':this.options.opacity,
                'width':container.width(),
                'height':container.height(),
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0px',
                'left':'0px',
                'z-index':99999
        }).addClass('ajax_overlay');
        // add an overiding class name to set new loader style 
        if (this.options.classOveride) {
            overlay.addClass(this.options.classOveride);
        }
        // insert overlay and loader into DOM 
        container.append(
            overlay.append(
                $('<div></div>').addClass('ajax_loader')
            ).fadeIn(this.options.duration)
        );
    };

    this.remove = function(){
        var overlay = this.container.children(".ajax_overlay");
        if (overlay.length) {
            overlay.fadeOut(this.options.classOveride, function() {
                overlay.remove();
            });
        }   
    }

    this.init();
}   
</script>





<input type="file" name="myfile">
<input type="submit"  id = "upload" value="Upload">    
<div id= "loading_gif">
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#upload").click(function () {     

var loader;
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){  
        loader = new ajaxLoader('body', options);
    });
var options = {
    bgColor         : '#fff',
    duration        : 800,
    opacity     : 0.7,
    classOveride    : false
}

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: {
            file: myfile
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Data has been Uploaded: ");
           $(document).ajaxcomplete(function(){   
        if (loader) loader.remove();
    });
          }
       });
     });
  });



<?php
$temp_location = "tmp/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{    
  if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
  {
     echo "File loading error! ";
  }
  else
  {        
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],
    $temp_location. $_FILES["myfile"]       ["name"]);

    //read myfile and insert data into database

    echo "File uploaded into database";
   } 
  }
?>
```