# Javascript/jquery hide loading image from select files screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [this image show/hide script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533202/3041290)

Instead of using a `submit` button, I want to submit the form by using `onchange submit` in the file select field. Until here, everything is working fine. However, when I click the `cancel` button in the (pup-up) file select screen, the loading image won't hide. I have no clue how to solve this, and any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: do you catch the onclick on the cancel button ? 

i'd say trigger hideLoading if you click the cancel, and remove the src from the image or the whole img element.

Comment: @KonstantinKrass Is it possible to catch the onlick cancel button from the standard browser file select window, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4628563/3041290) they say it isn't? When this is possible, I agree that triggering hideLoading would work.

Comment: ah you mean the default hmn...yeah maybe check for empty field onchange. it should be empty. and if it's no empty->submit and show loading